# Submitting data to MySQL with PHP OOP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, oop

I have updated the script to see if anyone can help me figure out what is wrong. I added error reporting all functions to help me find the error but I just keep getting a blank page(It still doesn't submit). I am having an issue with a simple submit form submitting data to mysql. I have done this dozens of times but for some reason it isn't working right now and I can't seem to find out why. First I define the DB, then I connect, test the connection or exit if fails. Once connected I test the fields aren't empty, store them in a variable and create a var with the query in it. Once the query is submitted I test the submission was successful and send the uploaded files to the correct folder, return a success or failed and close the DB connection. The code is below.

```
define("SERVER","IP Addy");
define("USER","DB User");
define("PASSWORD","DB Pass");
define("DATABASE","DB Table Name");

    $Con = new mysqli(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);

if(!empty($_POST['companyName']) || !empty($_POST['address']) || !empty($_POST['city']) || !empty($_POST['state']) || !empty($_POST['zip']) || !empty($_POST['website']) || !empty($_POST['number']) || !empty($_POST['fax']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_FILES['coverPhoto']) || !empty($_POST['mapsLink']) || !empty($_POST['mapsIframe']) || !empty($_POST['pinterest']) || !empty($_POST['facebook']) || !empty($_POST['twitter']) || !empty($_POST['google']) || !empty($_POST['yelp']) || !empty($_POST['description'])) {

    if($Con->connect_errno){
        printf("Could not connect to MySQL Database: %s \n",$Con->connect_error);
        exit;
    } else{

    $companyName = $_POST['companyName'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $fax = $_POST['fax'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $coverPhoto = $_FILES['coverPhoto']['name'];
    $mapsLink = $_POST['mapsLink'];
    $mapsIframe = $_POST['mapsIframe'];
    $pinterest = $_POST['pinterest'];
    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
    $twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
    $google = $_POST['google'];
    $yelp = $_POST['yelp'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $memberSince = date("M-DD-YY");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (dealerName,address,city,state,zip,website,number,fax,email,coverPhoto,mapsLink,mapsIframe,pinterest,facebook,twitter,google,yelp,description,memberSince) VALUES ('$companyName','$address','$city','$state','$zip','$website','$number','$fax','$email','$coverPhoto','$mapsLink','$mapsIframe','$pinterest','$facebook','$twitter','$google','$yelp','$description','$memberSince')";

    $query = $Con->query($sql);

    if($query === TRUE) {
        foreach($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array) {

            if(is_uploaded_file($file_array['temp_name'])){
                move_uploade_file($file_array['temp_name']);
                "$file_dir/".$file_array['name'];
                    echo"File was moved.";

            } else {
                echo "<div style=\"position:absolute;\"><p>No file found.</p></div>";
            }
        }
      }
    }
        $Con->close();
}
```

Comment: Are you actually getting the data? Do a `print_r($_POST)` on the page you're posting to.

Comment: You're not escaping the inputs, that could lead to the INSERT query failing (although it doesn't sound like that's the issue here). Does the $Con->error report anything?

Comment: @Mave What if I am not posting to a page? I am just submitting to MySQL. Are you referring to the page with the submit script or the html page?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins No it does not seem to be sending me any error reports. At first it was blank until I added the testing for data that was typed in the input. I also added the E_ALL(); and the only error that gave me was that the E_ALL(); function itself was unexpected.

Comment: @RookieRecruits If you're not posting to a page, then you'll never have data in `$_POST`. What page is in your `<form method="post" action="">` action?

Comment: I agree with @GeoffAtkins you could potentially be sql injecting yourself. You should use a prepared statement. You should also post your form and a `var_dump($_POST)`. Adding `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script and making sure you display errors, you will also see detailed error messages if anything goes wrong with any of the mysqli calls.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins what you are referring to may not be the case because I am testing first if the fields are empty() and it returns the true response (Saying they are empty) so is it even getting to the query submit portion to begin with?

Comment: @jeroen ok I will try your suggestions to see what I come up with.

Comment: @Mave the page in the action=" " is the correct file name. I checked for it to make sure I was submitting to the correct page. In that page I test if they are empty first then I test if they are not after which I begin to store $_POST[' '] into variables which I then use to submit the query.

Comment: @RookieRecruits Are the variables set or are they not set before you try to put them into `$reg`?

Comment: what is the method are you using in your form tag? it should be method="post"

Comment: @HradayJoshi Yes the mthod is post.

Comment: There is something I seem to be alone in not understanding in your question: HOW is it actually not working? Do you get the "Data was successfully submitted message" but finally don't find any inserted record, or do you get the "Data submission failed..." message (in such case, what is the `$Con->error` part?), or is it something else? BTW note that you didn't backtick escaped `table` in your query while it's a reserved word: this must logically fire an error.

Comment: @cFreed No I do not get either of the message, just a blank page and records also do not insert. The word table is just there to display that a table name goes there. Was that what you meant by that question? I get ($Con->error) from the initial connection up top.

Comment: If you get a blank page, sure it means that you didn't enter inside of the `if(!empty...` condition. As already pointed by others here, you should ensure what is the `$_POST` variables state, either with `print_r($_POST)` or merely controlling them using FIrebug if you can.

Comment: @cFreed ok thank you, that's helpful and thanks to everyone else for taking the time. I will use your examples to come to a solution.